# VBA - Send command which in cells to CMD to run

Tags: vba, excel, cmd

Here is my situation:
we need to create a folder and grant the folder permission for new staff everyday and i am creating the excel with VBA Macros. I want to make it like that, after input the user ID, the command (use it in CMD) will generated in other cell (e.g. D6 - D10, depend how many new staff on that day), and when i press the button, the folder with created with the name of the user id. And i want to add a msgbox saying the folder has been created with no error.

Here is the excel: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBDPZ.png

what i want to do is to make a button, press it and the folder created, i have tried for 2 days and got many outcome

1. the folder created with the name XXXXXXmd  (md is the command for CMD, i dunno why it becoming the filename.
2. folder created successfully, but error prompt in CMD (see pic) 
    https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYmEk.png
3. the button wont work if there are cells with no value.

here is my code, the range in excel is D6 to D55, here only what i test:

```
Sub Button8_Click()

Dim strBaseCmd As String
Dim r1 As Range
Dim r2 As Range
Dim r3 As Range
Dim r4 As Range
Dim r5 As Range
Dim strParameter As String
Dim strCmd As String


' base command
strBaseCmd = "CMD /K"

' get a cell from a sheet in this workbook
Set r1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Create Users Home Drive").Range("d6")
Set r2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Create Users Home Drive").Range("d7")
Set r3 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Create Users Home Drive").Range("d8")
Set r4 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Create Users Home Drive").Range("d9")
Set r5 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Create Users Home Drive").Range("d10")
strParameter = r1.Value & "              " & r2.Value & "              " & r3.Value & "              " & r4.Value & "              " & r5.Value

 ' add parameter to command
strCmd = strBaseCmd & strParameter

' run command
Shell strCmd, vbNormalFocus

End Sub
```

Do you have any idea on it, thank you very much for helping.

Comment: Thanks for you help. I can create the folder with your code. but now saying path not found error when execute the code. I believe it is because some of the cell has no value or it already exceeded my excel form area, the excel formula only from D6 to D55, there is nothing after D55. is there anyway to make the code execute from D6 to D55 only with no error (path not found)??

Answer (score 1):

You encounter the issues because of the way you pass the parameters. I don't see a space between `/K` and first parameter you send to cmd. I believe that your first command looks like:

```
CMD /Kmd \\myPath
```

I would suggest you the following:

Either loop through your cells with `while` or `do while` and run the CMD command for each cell that has a value. If you don't like the multiple CMD windows, you can create a bat file and execute that one.

Or use mkdir function which is part of the VBA instead of CMD command. [Mkdir documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/mkdir-statement).

```
Dim I as integer
I = 6 'Start with D6
While ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Create Users Home Drive").Cells(I,4).Value <> ""
    MkDir ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Create Users Home Drive").Cells(I,4).Value
    I = I + 1
Wend
```

Comment: Thanks for you help. I can create the folder with your code. but now saying path not found error when execute the code. I believe it is because some of the cell has no value or it already exceeded my excel form area, the excel formula only from D6 to D55, there is nothing after D55. is there anyway to make the code execute from D6 to D55 only with no error (path not found)??

Comment: The condition in `while` should have stopped the code when first empty cell was found. You can change the condition to `while I<=55`. `I` is the row index.